# Worried about movement in a floating shelf style mantel shelf

Tags: wood-movement

I'd like to replace our mantel shelf over the holidays. The plan is to have something that looks like a large beam but is constructed like a floating shelf (box). Haven't picked the exact variety yet, but right now I think it will be cherry but I have some questions about wood movement.

- If I simply rip 3 sides and 45 degrees and make a box with caps on the end, am I asking for trouble as the wood expands?
- If I were to make the box out of plywood and then glue thinner (say 1/4 inch) cherry to the plywood box, is that less likely to move?

Here's an example of the style of box [image]

Comment: Wood movement on boards this narrow is rarely an issue in practice, this is why it can safely be ignored on the pieces that form a table apron for example.

Comment: @Graphus is there a rule of thumb as to when it becomes a problem? If say I had to glue 2 or 3 of boards this width to make a panel I'd assume I would need to worry?

Comment: No rule of thumb, it's dependent on cut and species. With a glue-up of 2-3 boards you would sometimes have to make allowance, but depends on the total width (as well as cut of the wood and species). You can often ignore it up to the size of a small tabletop (narrow hall tables, lamp stands, that sort of thing) but beyond that it's best to take it into account.

Comment: You can completely eliminate any issue by strategic fastening. To minimize seasonal gap formation, I'd orient the end cap grain horizontally (ie, wrap-around from the front). You can fasten it to the front securely (say with pocket holes) from the inside. there are multiple ways to accommodate any wood movement depending on your joinery - if you're using screws into corner blocks, just use extra wide holes from the screws towards the back. Let me know if that's confusing and I'll attempt a picture ;-)